# Proxy's First Navigation Property is null when Seeding EF 4.1

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

When `Initializer.Seed()` uses `DbContext.DbSet.Find()` to set the navigation properties for a new Proxy, it correctly assigns the FK's to the Proxy, but the *first* navigation property is always null when I break on `SaveChanges()` and inspect the Proxy. Does anyone know why it does this?

(Sorry, I can't post a screenshot of the locals window.)

Model

```
public class Thing : Base {
    public virtual Nullable<int> Option1ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Option1 Option1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Nullable<int> Option2ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Option2 Option2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Nullable<int> Option3ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Option3 Option3 { get; set; }
}
public class Option1 : Base {
    public virtual ICollection<Thing> Things { get; set; }
}
public class Option2 : Base {
    public virtual ICollection<Thing> Things { get; set; }
}
public class Option3 : Base {
    public virtual ICollection<Thing> Things { get; set; }
}
public class Base {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext

```
public class Context : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Thing> Things { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Option1> Option1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Option2> Option2s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Option3> Option3s { get; set; }

    public ObjectContext ObjectContext {
        get { return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext; }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Seed()

```
var option1s = new List<Option1> {
    new Option1{Name="Red"},
    new Option1{Name="Green"}};
    option1s.ForEach(x => db.Option1s.Add(x));
    db.SaveChanges();
var option2s = new List<Option2> {
    new Option2{Name = "Tall"},
    new Option2{Name = "Short"}};
    option2s.ForEach(x => db.Option2s.Add(x));
    db.SaveChanges();
var option3s = new List<Option3> {
    new Option3{Name = "Male"},
    new Option3{Name = "Female"}};
    option3s.ForEach(x => db.Option3s.Add(x));
    db.SaveChanges();

var thing = db.Things.Create();
    thing.Option1 = db.Option1s.Find(1); //the first thing.XXXX shows null no matter what order
    thing.Option2 = db.Option2s.Find(1); //but the FK's work for all three of them
    thing.Option3 = db.Option3s.Find(1);
db.Things.Add(thing);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I believe this to be a bug.  I've added an edit below.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  I don't know what you did there, but you made the object state tracker very angry.

**EDIT:**

I believe this to be some sort of bug in the debugger and the way it works with dynamic proxies.  I say this because you can do `Console.WriteLine(thing.Option1.Id);` and it will give you the correct id.  If you get rid of the dynamic proxy by saying `var thing = new Thing();`, the debugger problem goes away.

Here is the more standard way to do what you're trying to do.

```
    var option1s = new List<Option1> {
            new Option1{Name="Red"},
            new Option1{Name="Green"}};
    option1s.ForEach(x => db.Option1s.Add(x));

    var option2s = new List<Option2> {
            new Option2{Name = "Tall"},
            new Option2{Name = "Short"}};
    option2s.ForEach(x => db.Option2s.Add(x));

    var option3s = new List<Option3> {
            new Option3{Name = "Male"},
            new Option3{Name = "Female"}};
    option3s.ForEach(x => db.Option3s.Add(x));

    var thing = db.Things.Create();
    thing.Option1 = option1s[0];
    thing.Option2 = option2s[0];
    thing.Option3 = option3s[0];

    db.Things.Add(thing);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I called `db.Things.Add(thing)` right after calling `Create()` and the problem went away. Though, it had been working despite the debugging confusion as you pointed out. It seems like it did weird stuff with the first property when `_changeTracker` was null. I also added a method to the context that both creates and adds a new proxy so that I won't forget to set the EntityState in the future. What do you think? Was it my fault for not Adding the entity in the first place? Or is it supposed to handle freshly created entities the way I had it?