# EF6 - Adding new associated child not populating Navigation Properties

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following code which adds members to a parent group. The issue I'm running into is that the LAST member added to the PCSGroupMembers collection will not load it's navigation properties on demand. I have a set of 3 I've tried adding in various orders... the first 2 always work, the last one won't load the nav properties.

In the case below, you'll see 6 members total. The last 3 are the ones I just added in this request are the SAME IDS as the first 3 (unique key is groupid, memberid, startdate), so I know for sure there isn't an issue with a "bad FK" or similar. The first two of the new members are building out their nav properties, but that last one never does. Doesn't matter if I'm adding 2, 3, 4, etc. Last one never populates.

What seems REALLY odd to me is the `PcsGroupID` is an empty Guid on that last one even though it got added to the group via `group.PcsGroupMembers.add(pcsMember)` in the code below.

*Edit*: If you see the block labeled **Hack**, however, the real final  member now has it's Nav properties. The faked temp member is then removed from the collection (and context) and everything magically works. So....WAT?

**Code to add new members**

```
//expire all existing members ([0..2] in this example)
group.PCSGroupMembers
  .Where(m => m.EndDate == null)
  .ToList().ForEach(m => {
    m.EndDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
  });

//add new members from request ([3..5] in this example)
foreach (PcsGroupMemberAddViewModel member in requestViewModel.Members) {
  PCSGroupMember pcsMember = db.PCSGroupMembers.Create();
  pcsMember.PCSSplitID = Guid.NewGuid();
  pcsMember.ProjectProtocolID = member.ProjectProtocolID;
  pcsMember.SplitAmount = member.Split;
  pcsMember.IsPrimary = member.IsPrimary;
  pcsMember.StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

  group.PCSGroupMembers.Add(pcsMember);
}
```

**Second to last** (index 4)
[image: Associations populating]

**Last Child** (index 5)
[image: associations not populating]

**Hack**

```
var tempmember = db.PCSGroupMembers.Create();
//this Add seems to trigger the previous 'real' item to load it's Nav properties.... ???
group.PCSGroupMembers.Add(tempmember); 
group.PCSGroupMembers.Remove(tempmember); //remove from collection
db.PCSGroupMembers.Remove(tempmember); //remove from context
```

Comment: Maybe some proxy flakiness? Similar issue (and old): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783484/proxys-first-navigation-property-is-null-when-seeding-ef-4-1

Comment: Yeah, I can find some references to EF4.x with issues like this, but none of those seemed to explain what was going on. I added a 'Hack' above which has resolved my problem, but doesn't really explain what's going on under the covers in EF. Seems like a possible bug, but I'm still so new to EF, I might just be royally stupid.